# Is there any use case of DAA (Direct Anonymous Attestation) in TPM?

Tags: digital-signature, tpm, trusted-computing, remote-attestation

I want to know the use cases of DAA (Direct Anonymous Attestation) in the real world.

Comment: Seems like intel uses in their Enhanced Privacy ID